# Is there something I can put in my React package.json to update the url of my backend fetching?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm currently in the process of deploying a MERN stack app. I'm putting the frontend on Netlify and the backend on Adaptable. I need to change the fetching on the frontend so that it goes to the Adaptable site instead of my localhost, but I don't want to manually change every fetch. During development I was using a proxy in the package.json and then just had the simple route in the fetch like `'/api/login'`. Is there a similar thing I can add to the package.json so that I can quickly change all the fetching rather than go into each fetch manually?

Here is my package.json for my frontend:

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is an example of one of my fetch requests:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/checklist', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
  }
})
```

The backend url will be something like this: `https://foobar-backend.adaptable.app/`

Comment: Why in the package file, not using existing features like https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: It looks like you're re-inventing environment variables.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I would still have to go to every place I have a fetch and add in process.env

Comment: Not if you factor it out sensibly you don't. And using a dev proxy only makes sense if it'll also be making relative requests _in production_, which this requirement suggests isn't the case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see - will go with env then